# decomposition of $-2x^2-3xy+2y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to decompose $-2x^2-3xy+2y^2$ 
there are the following steps:

$-2x^2-3xy+2y^2=0\Rightarrow (-2x^2-4xy)+(2y^2+xy)=0\Rightarrow -2x(x+2y)+y(2y+x)=0\Rightarrow (y-2x)(x+2y)=0$

is there a general form to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a quadratic polynomial in $x$, you can use the quadratic formula in order to find its roots:
$$r_1=\frac{3y+\sqrt{9y^2+16y^2}}{-4}=-2y\qquad\text{and}\qquad r_2=\frac{3y-\sqrt{9y^2+16y^2}}{-4}=\frac{1}{2}y$$
So:
$$-2x^2-3xy+2y^2=-2\left(x+2y\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}y\right)=\boxed{\color{blue}{(-2x+y)(x+2y)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would have used:

$$
x=\frac{3y\pm\sqrt{9 y^2+16 y^2\ }}{-4} = \frac{3y\pm5 y}{-4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a homogeneous polynomial of two variables, it means, it is the defining polynomial of a one-dimensional projective "curve", which has affine parts. It's interesction with the $[x:1]$ affin subspace can coordinated, as $$-2X^2-3X+2=(1-2X)(X+2).$$ Then looking at this curve again as an affine one, we get $$-2x^2-3xy+2y^2=(y-2x)(x+2y).$$